# Extended celery.schedules.schedule objects aren't passed extra arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery, celerybeat

[The code is here.](https://github.com/charlesthomas/coyote/blob/master/coyote/utils/scheduler.py#L6)

I wrote an extension of the `celery.schedules.schedule` interface, and I can't figure out why it's getting instantiated with nothing set in the extra values I created.

When I instantiate them before passing to `app.conf.CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` they're correct. But all the ones that celery beat instantiates are incorrect.

I asked in #celery IRC chan and the only response I got was about lazy mode, but that's for `celery.beat.Scheduler`, not `celery.schedules.schedule`, so if it's relevant, I don't understand how. Do I have to extend that too, just so that it instantiates the schedules correctly?

I've tried digging into the celery code w/the debugger to figure out where these schedules are getting instantiated and I can't find it. I can see when they come back from `Unpickler` they are wrong, but I can't find where they get created or where they get pickled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`celery.schedules.schedule` has a `__reduce__` method that defines how to serialize and reconstruct the object using pickle:

https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/schedules.py#L150-L151

When pickle serializes the object it will call:

```
fun, args = obj.__reduce__()
```

and when it reconstructs the object it will do:

```
obj = fun(*args)
```

So if you've added new state to your custom schedule subclass, passed as arguments to `__init__`, then you will
also have to define a `__reduce__` method that takes these
new arguments into account:

```
class myschedule(schedule):

    def __init__(self, run_every=None, relative=False, nowfun=None,
                 odds=None, max_run_every=None, **kwargs):
        super(myschedule, self).__init__(
            run_every, relative, nowfun, **kwargs)
        self.odds = odds
        self.max_run_every = max_run_every

    def __reduce__(self):
        return self.__class__, (
            self.run_every, self.relative, self.nowfun,
            self.odds, self.max_run_every)
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of time in the Python debugger, I narrowed the problem down to celery.beat.PersistentScheduler.sync() and/or shelve.sync() (which is called by the former).

When the shelve is synced, the values are getting lost. I don't know why, but I'm pretty sure it's a bug in either Celery or Shelve.

[In any case, I wrote a workaround.](https://github.com/charlesthomas/coyote/commit/b401b085e8627ac100b7b0905ed2f2bbb2582149)